# Function that checks type guard against union type and returns a type which is the opposite of the detected type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a function that checks if a value of union type `A | B` is `A` and if so throws an error, otherwise returns the value as `B`, so that the caller can disregard `A`?

Example:

```
type FailedResult = {
  error: string;
};

function isFailed(result: any): result is FailedResult {
  return 'error' in result;
}

function processResult<T>(result: T)  {
  if (isFailed(result)) {
    throw new Error('Error!');
  }

  return result; // If T was "A | FailedResult" we now want to return as A, i.e., "T minus FailedResult"
}

const result: {foo: number} | {error: string} = {foo: 42};

const notFailed = processResult(result); // want notFailed to be typed as {foo: number}
```

I tried using an `infer` type, but unsurprisingly it did not work:

```
type NotError<T> = T extends FailedResult | infer A ? A : never;
```

... supposedly because if `T` is of type `A | FailedResult` then `A` could still be `{foo: number} | FailedResult`.

So what I need is to be able to say that *if* this type `A | {error :string}` is *not* `{error :string}`, I want to infer a type which is not simply `A` (since `A` could itself contain `{error: string}`) but rather `A | {error: string}` _minus `{error: string}`. In other words, if `T` is `A | B` and I know it's not `A` I want to get the type `T minus A`.

Comment: `Exclude<T, FailedResult>` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make sure the argument is always a union type, you can just add `| FailedResult` to the `result` parameter:

```
function processResult<T>(result: T | FailedResult)  {
  if (isFailed(result)) {
    throw new Error('Error!');
  }

  return result;
}

const result: {foo: number} | {error: string} = {foo: 42};

const notFailed = processResult(result); // inferred type: {foo: number}
```

If you call `processResult` with a bare `FailedResult` it will infer a `FailedResult` return type though, whereas `never` would be more appropriate.

```
const noUnion = processResult({error: 'oops'}) // inferred type: {error: string}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgSwDYQCYCUIGcCuThQC8UA3gLABQUUEATrQPa0BcUWwtCAdgOYDclAL4CKlAGY4uAY2AIGXKAizxkaABS1seYKzhcQASlabc+RVliIUGLWfJUom4DloKA5HUa03ihSe0igpTikjJyCmCMUthYmKbAADwAKgB8GrY6UElQAD6WqjbxBtT21AhiUGpKKtbpRcWl1FDAABaMAO5QXBCdAKL0TGpu-V4AhG4GItRBog5OLn4ZQsEUUvLsjhmsJGIMDKxcOAC2AEZ0grmknkys7Jy8F8Q7e6wALABMwitrXBtcDMAamgiFBIgxolhYhk6tpJlAAPTw3xiTzA0CQba7fZdY5nWgzSg-P4MACqXHCILBEKh8TUJGuLCgbj2YCwbkExURyNRqGa4Ag2wZtw43B4MyAA)

Alternatively, you can use an explicit cast on the result of `processResult`, making the type guard redundant. For this you could define a type

```
type ExcludeFailedResult<T> =
  T extends FailedResult ? FailedResult extends T ? never : T : T
```

As `ExcludeFailedResult` distributes over unions, `ExcludeFailedResult<T1 | FailedResult>` evaluates to `ExcludeFailedResult<T1> | ExcludeFailedResult<FailedResult>`, yielding `T1`. The double `extends` conditions make sure only the exact `FailedResult` gets filtered out.

Using `ExcludeFailedResult`, `processResult` becomes

```
function processResult<T>(result: T)  {
  if (isFailed(result)) {
    throw new Error('Error!');
  }

  return result as ExcludeFailedResult<T>;
}

const notFailed = processResult({} as {foo: number} | {error: string});
// inferred type: {foo: number}

const noUnion = processResult({error: 'oops'})
// inferred type: never

const overlap = processResult({} as {foo: number, error: string} | {error: string})
// inferred type: {foo: number} | {error: string}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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%20ei7cGxeSqTSoPSSPqU6yE5QgA)

Comment: Hmm, yes that does work! I did not even try that because I was sure that even if `result` is `T | FailedResult`, nothing stops `T` from also including an `error: string` property. But I tried your playground, also tweaking it to make sure TS doesn't know that `result` is in fact `{foo:42}` at compile time. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Keep in mind it's still a bit iffy though with the possible overlap. To type it properly something like `type Result<T> = {result: T} | {error: string}` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks nasty but you can do this:

```
function processResult<T extends typeof result>(result: T)  {
  if (isFailed(result as FailedResult)) {
    throw new Error('Error!');
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This gives `TS2304: Cannot find name 'result'`. I'm also not understanding, how could `T` extend the type of `result`, which in turn is of type `T`? It seems very circular.

Comment: not result inside a function, but `result` const that you've defined

Comment: [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgSwDYQCYCUIGcCuThQC8UA3gFBRQQBO1A9tQFxRbDUIB2A5gNxkC+fMgDMcHAMbAEdDlARZ4yNAApq2PMGZwOIAJTM1ufHKyxEKDOuPlKa4DmqyA5DXrUnc2YY19+ZEWKS0rJg9OLYWJhGwAA8ACpUAB7AEByopqCQdMJQ3vgAfKpWmlBxupQ2cjnK8ooWRdFQcKZ1aFEauuWVlMAAFvQA7lAcEEMAorQMyk4TbgCETrp8lH62EPaOucW+-uIyrFvRzCTCdHTMHDgAtgBGNPxQAD6krgzMrOzcD8QnZ8wALAAmQS7fYEDh0YCtVBEKChOjhLCRYoNDo8KAAegxUAG2nBkOhUGAdCgdyJ4DQTVMv3Ow2ud2o-CAA)

Comment: Thanks, but surely this works only because TypeScript has a const literal that it knows is of type `{foo: 42}`? When looking at your playground, both the input parameter and the return value was typed the same - no FailedResult component anywhere. I updated the example to put the call inside a function that has a variable of type `{foo: number} | FailedResult` which it doesn't know anything more about, and now the `FailedResult` portion is _not_ stripped.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around some more I realized it's probably as easy as `T extends FailedResult ? never : T`, i.e., something like this:

```
type FailedResult = {
  error: string;
};

type NotError<T> = T extends FailedResult ? never : T;

function isFailed(result: any): result is FailedResult {
  return 'error' in result;
}

function processResult<T>(result: T): NotError<T>  {
  if (isFailed(result)) {
    throw new Error('Error!');
  }
  return result as NotError<T>;
}

function test(r: {foo: number} | FailedResult) {
  const notError = processResult(r)
  
  const foo: number = notError.foo; // we now that notError is of type {foo: number}
}
```

Comment: This will return `never` if `T` happens to have a `error: string` property: e.g. `processResult({} as {foo: number, error: string} | {error: string})` has type `never`. Maybe that's okay for your use case though. With the possible overlap between `T` and `FailedResult`, all solutions will have quirky edge cases.

Comment: Actually, that can be fixed with an extra `extends`, let me include it in my answer for completeness.